# sed: how to extract a part of a line containing colon

Tags: bash, sed

I want to extract the date part inside parentheses with sed:

```
# Equ_time  =  959240309.430000 (26-May-2015 07:38:29)
```

I use this code:

```
sed -n 's:# Equ_time  =  [0-9]*.[0-9]* .\([0-9]*.[A-Z]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*\).*:\1:p' file.txt
```

but it returns:

```
26-May-2015 07
```

I think the problem is related to colon character in time section, How should I change the command to work fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change it to

```
sed -n 's:# Equ_time  =  [0-9]*.[0-9]* .\([0-9]*.[A-Z]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9:]*\).*:\1:p' file.txt
```

Notice I added a colon in the last `[0-9:]*`. The error was because you hadn't included a colon in your regex search

Comment: Thanks, but would you please tell me what does that colon you added do?

Comment: The time part of your text `07:38:29` has a colon in it. You need to tell your regex to search for a colon as well. Hence the colon added in the code.

Comment: OK, but why did you only add colon in the last part which is related to the seconds part of the time section? Why didn't you add colon to the parts representing colons (separators) in time?

Comment: Since the `[0-9:]*` regex means select all numbers and colons, it represents your whole time. To make your regex more efficient, you can change it to `sed -n 's:# Equ_time  =  [0-9]*.[0-9]* .\([ :0-9A-Za-z\-]*\).*:\1:p' file.txt` with `[ :0-9A-Za-z\-]*` representing your datetime combined.

Comment: Whatever the OP really needs, that sed script is definitely **not** the right answer as it's over-complicated, non-portable, and fragile (will falsely match other strings).

Answer (score 2):

If this isn't all you need:

```
$ awk -F'[ (]' '{print $8}' file
26-May-2015
```

then edit your question to clarify your requirements and provide more truly representative sample input. Right now you have a very complicated approach that's definitely unnecessary as you could do a more robust match more simply  with:

```
$ sed -n 's:# Equ_time  =  [0-9]*\.[0-9]* .\([^ ]*\).*:\1:p' file
26-May-2015
```

but that's probably not even necessary either and without better sample input and the associated output it's hard to guess at what the right approach is.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the marked parts in your input string and the pattern:

```
# Equ_time  =  959240309.430000 (26-May-2015 07:38:29)
                                    ^^^

.\([0-9]*.[A-Z]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*.[0-9]*\)
          ^^^^^
```

The character class `[A-Z]` will only match uppercase letters, not lowercase ones. (in the C locale, that is: in other locales it might match just about anything.) So that part will match exactly once (against the `M`), and the `a`  and `y` will be matched by the following dots. Since you didn't spell out the actual separators (`-` and `:`), and used `[0-9]*` instead of `[0-9]+` the rest of the pattern will match partially.

I would condense your sed to something like this, if you're not overly worried about matching the exact format:

```
sed -nEe 's/^# Equ_time *=[0-9. ]*\((.*)\).*/\1/p'
```

or, if you want the inner part matched up to a character, then

```
([0-9]+-[A-Za-z]+-[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+)
```

(note that I used extended regexes there)